# div height adjusting doesn't include margin of its content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with a table inside. The table is styled with bootstrap by applying the table-class. By default table in bootstrap has a margin-bottom of 20px.

My div adjusts its height to the visible content of the table but doesn't include the margin of the table.

I would like to style the div with a border-left, having more than one of those divs on top of each other with a continuos border. But there's always a gap due to the (invisible) margin of the table.

Here is a fiddle of a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/bj13hez3/2/

html:

```
<div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>table</td>
        <td>content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>other</td>
        <td>table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

css:

```
div { border-left: 2px solid #d7d7d7; }
```

If I put a border on all sides of the div, the height seams to adjust correctly to the table including its margin. I could do something like

```
div { border: 2px solid transparent;
      border-left: 2px solid #d7d7d7;}
```

but then there will be a small 2px gap between the divs corresponding to top/bottom border.
As later I only want to show the border on hover/mouseover, this could be a solution for me (2px probably won't catch someones eye) but it's not really nice.

What can I do to make my div / border to have the height of the complete content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To include the `margin` of the children, you need to add `overflow: hidden`. The possible explanation for this is as below.

Few possible solutions for this issue include:

```
div { border: 2px solid transparent;
      overflow: hidden;}

div table {display: block;}
```

The browser always collapses the margins with the nearby margins. When you give an `overflow: hidden`, it calculates all the contents inside it's box model and makes it confine to the content.

*Sorry about my quick dirty handwriting...*

[image]

This is the same case with `float`s too. Floated items do not occupy any space. Have a look here:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

But the same thing, if the parent has an `overflow: hidden` it doesn't happen:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

A whole big article about this concept here: [What You Should Know About Collapsing Margins](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/). The `overflow` is such a powerful property that it works for everything. But when it comes to `position` you need to use it carefully!

The `position` works like `float`, in the way that both do not take the layout. For eg., see the below snippet:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="position: absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

Where, if you play with it in the wrong way:

```css
div {padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666;}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute;"></div>
</div>
```

The contents above get cut. Hope it is clear.